# decode JSON string to class object

Tags: json, swift, decode, codable

```
 private func createWeatherObjectWith(json: Data, x:Any.Type ,completion: @escaping (_ data: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let weather = try decoder.decode(x.self, from: json)
            return completion(weather, nil)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error creating current weather from JSON because: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
```

Here I write above code to decode JSON string to class object by passing class type. But it gives the following error

```
Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Any.Type, from: Data)'
```

Comment: I think you need to convert it into object instead of decoding

Comment: You should provide the full code you try to run including the JSON (in a Playground compatible way) and your Codable class/struct. That will enable us to help you properly. Please edit your question and do not post code in comments in order to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to decode any type of object then use these technique

**1. Generics function**

```
private func createWeatherObjectWith<T: Decodable>(json: Data, Object:T.Type ,completion: @escaping (_ data: T?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let weather = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: json)
        return completion(weather, nil)
    } catch let error {
        return completion(nil, error)
    }
}
```

**2. Extend Decodable**

```
extension Decodable {
    static func map(JSONString:String) -> Self? {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            return try decoder.decode(Self.self, from: Data(JSONString.utf8))
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
let user = User.map(JSONString:"your JSON string")
let users = [User].map(JSONString:"your JSON string")
```

Comment: Never call `localizedDescription` in a `Codable` catch block. Don't do that. You will get a generic error message rather than the real `Codable` error. Print always the entire `error` instance.

Comment: @vadian Better if use error exceptional handling rather than error codes.

Comment: Codable errors are very descriptive, there are no codes, the most significant information is in the `context` property.

Comment: Was not focusing on debugging part of this, but I agree with you that error is better for error handling and debugging rather than the localized description.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to decode any type of Object to String in Swift 4.1

```
func convertAnyObjectToJSONString(from object:Any) -> String? {

    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []) else { 

        return nil 
    }

    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) 
}
```

Comment: `Invalid top-level type in JSON write`

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple explanation. Decode "from string" rather than "from data".

Somewhat confusingly, you "normally" decode from data, not from a string:

```
let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(YourClass.self, from: data))
```

Sometimes, unusually, you will have an actual string, rather than data.

If so:

```
let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(YourClass.self, from: Data(someString.utf8)))
```

and that's it.

Whenever you need to convert a string to data, these days it's just

```
Data(someString.utf8)
```