# trying to decode value in swift 4.2 using its position in the json structure

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

How can I decode the following using swift Decodable? I'm only interested in the **extract** value

```
{  
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{  
      "normalized":[  ],
      "pages":{  
         "434325":{    //can be any number!
            "pageid":434325,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"asdfasdfsa",
            "extract":""
```

I'm attempting the following:

```
struct Entry: Decodable {
    let batchcomplete: String
    let query: Query

    struct Query: Decodable {
        let normalized: [String]
        let pages: Page

        struct Page: Decodable {
            let pageid: Entry // I think this is going to be an issue

            struct Entry: Decodable {
                let title: String
                let extract: String 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the extract like this:

```
  print(entry.query.pages.first.extract)
```

Is there a way to use **.first** for this ?

I'm only every going to get maximum one page so ideally I would just grab the first element.

Comment: Decoding JSON using Generics [Hope this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367491/decode-json-string-to-class-object-swift/53367705#53367705)

Comment: If you just need one value, SwiftyJSON might be easier to use.

Comment: this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268833/swift-4-decodable-with-unknown-dynamic-keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4 Decodable with keys not known until decoding time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598461/swift-4-decodable-with-keys-not-known-until-decoding-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decoding code is ok up until `Query type.

So what should be used instead:

```
struct Query: Decodable {
    let normalized: [String]
    let pages: [String: Page]

    struct Page: Decodable {
        let pageid: Int
        let title: String
        let extract: String
    }
}
```

So, key points:

1. If you don't know what keys would be there, use `[String: <SomeDecodableType>]` because any `JSON Object` can be mapped to the `[String: <Decodable>]`.
2. You don't need to declare `Page.Entry`, just put all the fields to the `Page`
3. To get `extract` instead of `entry.query.pages.first.extract` you will have to use `entry.query.pages.first?.value.extract` (`extract` of first random page, because `[String: Page]` is unsorted) or `entry.query.pages.sorted(by: sorter).first?.value.extract` (where `sorter` is some function, that takes two key-value pairs and returns true if first one should go before second one in order) to get `first` using some order.